# Webpack is reporting the wrong version number ...?

Tags: npm, webpack, version

When I run npm run webpack -v I get:

```
6.14.4
```

However when I look at the package.json file I can see it is:

```
"webpack": "^4.42.1",
```

Furthermore the current version I can find from the [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack) is (09/01/2021):

```
5.51.1
```

Why is it reporting the wrong version number when I use the -v option?

Comment: Run `npm exec webpack v`.

Answer (score 1):

`npm run webpack -v` returns you the installed npm version, not the webpack version. With npm run you run a script (defined in package.json), but webpack is not a script.

You have to run `npm exec webpack v` or `npx webpack v`, which will display the correct version number(s).